# How to properly organize multiple WPF/Entity Framework applications that share resources?

Tags: project-management, wpf, mvvm, project-structure, projects-and-solutions

Company A is building 5 separate in-house WPF applications, and they would like to share UserControls, ResourceDictionaries, and ADO Entity Data Models between each project. They would also like to incorporate 3rd Party libraries using Nuget. Should they incorporate all of these projects into one solution, or should they separate them into multiple solutions? What are the advantages of either approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would take the shared, and build nuget packages for them. Make a local repository and share them that way.